# How can the DVR/NVR handle many cameras while PC can't?

Tags: computer-hardware

First of all, I apologize for lack of information, but I have to start somewhere.

For those who have knowledge about this topic, can you tell me how PC can not handle more than 8 cameras while DVR/NVR handle many more?
I wonder if DVR/NVR uses special technique or its hardware is designed that way to handle cameras ? Or is it about the cameras that are special for /dedicated to DVRs/NVRs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be difficult to answer your question when the foundation of the question is in error. A search using "linux dvr software" returns many options. I selected the first and did a little digging.

[Bluecherry](https://www.bluecherrydvr.com/product/v3license/) is a Linux (PC) based program which allows one to use a computer as a DVR. The license page (linked) references an upper limit of 150 cameras.

I did not dig deeper, but I've seen other Linux DVR systems in the past, many of which are free. One of the free programs I've found is [Universal CMS DVR](https://learncctv.com/software-for-multiple-cctv-dvr-works-with-h-264-dvr/) which references in the setup instructions up to 64 cameras.

With wireless cameras and network connected cameras, one is not limited to USB ports or similar related capacity restrictions.

Comment: As I already said, I have to start somewhere and that means I nearly don't know anything about this topic. But I mark this one as answered since this question's foundation is in error as you said.
Thanks for your effort!